# First bin in ggplot histogram not the correct width

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

In the histogram that I created, I want the first bin to contain all people with the event occurring within the first month (i.e., time between 1.0-2.0), which corresponds to 57/141 (40.4%). However, in the histogram I produced, the first bar represents 48/141 (34.0%).

[image: Histogram]

I figured out that what my histogram is doing is that in the first bar (labelled as month 1), it is actually displaying the 47 people with a time to event between 1.0-1.5. It then proceeds to make month 2: 1.5-2.5, month 3: 2.5-3.5, etc.

I've tried adjusting the boundary, breaks, and bin width, but none of these has been successful. How do I get the bins of my histogram to be 1-2, 2-3, 3-4,... instead of 1-1.5, 1.5-2.5, 2.5-3.5,...?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

#Define data 
data <- data.frame (id= 1:141,
                  time = c(1.328767,33.909589,13.230137,32.331507,6.161644,20.167123,15.794521, 35.750685,3.958904,2.347945,1.756164,3.794521,46.961644,5.668493,14.775342,5.964384,15.268493,17.241096, 4.452055,17.372603,4.123288,28.945205,1.394521,9.515068,1.690411,5.734247,1.065753,5.405479,1.131507,8.39720,1.131507,1.065753,2.084932,13.460274,1.164384,6.786301,39.301370,1.197260,1.263014,1.098630,2.117808,1.230137,1.657534,1.065753,1.131507,13.986301,1.690411,1.065753,1.197260,2.249315,10.665753,1.690411,5.405479,4.452055,1.098630,1.065753,1.197260,1.065753,1.164384,1.493151,1.789041,1.394521,1.263014,17.701370,6.720548,24.605479,1.328767,13.197260,1.065753,4.189041,2.446575,30.852055,19.016438,28.813699,16.715068,29.438356,1.065753,1.230137,7.871233,4.386301,22.698630,1.295890,14.643836,1.131507,13.000000,3.991781,3.400000,17.964384,1.065753,2.512329,1.065753,3.827397,5.800000,21.745205,17.339726,1.164384,11.619178,9.515068,2.282192,4.189041,1.098630,1.065753,19.509589,25.591781,1.230137,28.747945,8.726027,1.065753,11.487671,30.720548,8.232877,19.871233,3.728767,1.986301,10.534247,8.956164,11.356164,11.520548,1.361644,4.484932,15.531507,1.493151,27.432877,10.468493,6.589041,1.065753,1.263014,1.065753,1.098630,35.421918,1.295890,9.810959,1.098630,21.547945,1.657534, 1.394521,1.065753,11.652055,1.164384,1.887671,1.098630))

#Create histogram 
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = time)) +  
  #Bin width is one month
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count)/sum(after_stat(count))),binwidth=1,fill="#ED0000B2",color="#FFFFFF") +
  #Set y-axis to represent percent
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(from=0,to=0.35,by=0.05),
                     expand=c(0,0),
                     labels=scales::percent,
                     limits=c(0, 0.35)) +
  #Set axis ticks to 3-month intervals
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(from=0,to=max(data$time),by=3),
                     expand=c(0,0)) +
  labs(title = 'Time to Event',
       caption=paste0("N=",n_distinct(data$id)),
       x = 'Months from Initiation', 
       y = '(%)') +
  #Update font to times new roman
  theme(text=element_text(size=12,  family="Times New Roman"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,face="bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust=0.5),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="#FFFFFF"),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.2, colour = "#000000", linetype=1))
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be simpler to convert `time` to integer month, then `count(month)` and plot a bar chart using `geom_col()` ?

Comment: Try adding `boundary = 0` to your geom_histogram. FYI, your scale_y_continuous is set to exclude from view any calculated columns larger than 0.35, which will hide your first bins if you align them as you intend.   `geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count)/sum(after_stat(count))), binwidth = 1, boundary = 0) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(from=0,to=0.40,by=0.05), expand=c(0,0), labels=scales::percent)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want a count per month, rather than a distribution. So it may be easier just to calculate the count per month and plot a bar chart.

Minimal code example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% 
  mutate(month = as.integer(time)) %>% 
  count(month) %>% 
  mutate(p = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month, p)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent())
```

Result:

[image]